# number of bits in an RGB image

Tags: embedded, rgb

Im chanced upon this statement while studying the allocation of RAM in embedded device.

Basically suppose we have an image sensor that uses RGB 5-6-5 format. It captures an image size of 320x240. The author proceeds to use

"There are two 150-KB data buffers that contain the raw data from the image sensor (320x240 in the
RGB 5-6-5 format). "

Does anyone know how is two 150KB data buffers enough to store the raw image? How can i calculate the image bits?

I tried calculating
( 2^5 * 2^6 * 2^5 * 320 * 240 ) * 0.000125 = 629145.6 // in KB.

Comment: You are calculating all possible different image you can get

Comment: Can you explain your calculation?  It is bizarre to say the least.  16 bits per pixel x 230 x 320 pixels is 1228800 bits, 153600 bytes or exactly 150 kibibyte. This is an off-topic question in SO - it being about your understanding of bitmaps and arithmetic rather than code

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, definitely have to work on these foundation properly before proceeding. (:

Answer (score 5):

You should look closer at the definition of the RGB 5:6:5 format. Each color takes up 2 bytes (5 bits for red, 6 bits for green and 5 bits for blue; adding up to 16 bits == 2 bytes), so a raw 320x240 picture takes `320 * 240 * 2` bytes, i.e. 153600 bytes or 150 KB.

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense, each pixel has RGB components which is a summates to 16 bits. Thank you!